# Writing parcelables to Parcel

Tags: android

I have a class that implements `Parcelable`. Three fields of this class are also `Parcelable` objects. When I write these fields to a Parcel, via dest.writeParcelable(mParcelableObject, 0) and try reading them back and setting the corresponding fields via `in.readParcelable(classLoader)` I get a `ClassCastException`. It seems that I cannot write multiple `Parcelables` to a `Parcel` and expect the system to figure out which of those Parcelables that were written correspond to which of my fields. In other words, if I write all of them and then read them in succession:

```
someFieldOfTypeA = in.readParcelable(classLoader)
someFieldOfTypeB = in.readParcelable(classLoader)
someFieldOfTypeC = in.readParcelable(classLoader)
```

..then I can never succeed in writing to `someFieldOfTypeB` from `readParcelable`. The reading assumes that the type of this `readParcelable` is of class type A, the first one that I wrote to when I did `writeParcelable`.

I hope this makes any sense.

So how can I write multiple parcelables and then read them and assign them to their corresponding fields without getting a `ClassCastException`?

Comment: Have you tried something like `someFieldOfTypeB = (classTypeB) in.readParcelable(classLoader);` ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, for me, I've had better luck calling FieldOfTypeB.CREATOR.writeToParcel(dest) directly (since those fields are themselves Parcelable).